# Casting from int to float in zig

Tags: zig

I'm trying to cast to float by calling `@as` on my variable, this works correctly if the variable is constant, but throws a compile error otherwise. How to correctly perform casting from int to float in zig?

```
pub fn main() void {
    var foo: u32 = 3;
    const bar: f32 = @as(f32, foo) / 5;
    foo = 42;
    std.debug.print("{d}", .{bar});
}

error: expected type 'f32', found 'u32'
    const bar: f32 = @as(f32, foo) / 5;
                              ^~~
```

Comment: https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#floatFromInt - e.g.: `const bar: f32 = @as(f32, @floatFromInt(foo)) / 5;`

Comment: Note that the `@as` here is also only necessary because of the `/ 5` part; Normally zig can figure out what it's supposed to cast to from context if type annotations are present.